# Browser cache overriding expires headers

Tags: .htaccess, caching, expires-header

I have a Joomla site, running on an Apache server and am having problems with Firefox and Chrome browsers caching the page and not serving the latest version.

I have added this code to my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 60 seconds"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 week"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

If I clear the browser cache in Chrome and Firefox then load the site, I get the correct response headers for images, css and javascript as per the code above.

For the main document I get these respond headers on the first load:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Wed, 17 Aug 2005 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
```

But when I reload the page or even open it in a new tab those expires headers disappear, and the browser loads up the cached web page (with status code 304 not modified).

I'm at a loss to understand what is happening here. I'm on a mac and use Safari which doesn't have any of these issues so I'm puzzled why Chrome and Firefox don't behave the way I expect them to.

Perhaps it could be explained why the page has a different set of response headers in relation to the expires than the default in htaccess. Is this the way mod_expires works?

I hope there's enough info here to answer my query, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this will help, take ref. by this link

http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-cache-limiter.php